# What does this MATLAB statement mean?

Tags: matlab

Regarding the following MATLAB statement shown on [the documentation page for `imopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html):

```
figure, imshow(I_opened, [])
```

What do `figure` and `[]` mean in the statement?

Comment: `figure` will create a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`figure()` creates a new window.

About your other question - taken from the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html):

> imshow(I,[low high]) displays the grayscale image I,...
>   If you use an empty matrix ([]) for [low high], imshow uses [min(I(:))
>   max(I(:))]; that is, the minimum value in I is displayed as black, and
>   the maximum value is displayed as white